# Strange error in C++ without stoping the program

Tags: c++, algorithm

When I change the value that I pass to my array I receive strange error which doesn't stop the program but it always appears so I'm curious why. I give you my code below:
My error is something like: In function 'int numOfDifferentElements(BSTree*, int)': control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] ( main.cpp:97:1 ) and there is an arrow pointing to:  }

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct BSTree
{
    int val;
    BSTree* up;
    BSTree* right;
    BSTree* left;
};
void AddBstNode(BSTree* &root, int valToAdd)
{
    {
        BSTree* pom;
        BSTree* nodeToAdd = new BSTree;
        nodeToAdd->val = valToAdd;
        nodeToAdd->left = NULL;
        nodeToAdd->right = NULL;
        nodeToAdd->up = NULL;

        if (root == NULL)
        {
            root = nodeToAdd;
        }
        else
        {
            pom = root;
            while (1)
            {
                if (nodeToAdd->val < pom->val)
                    if (pom->left == NULL)
                    {
                        pom->left = nodeToAdd;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        pom = pom->left;
                else if(nodeToAdd->val > pom->val)
                {
                    if (pom->right == NULL)
                    {
                        pom->right = nodeToAdd;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        pom = pom->right;
                }
                else // gdy wartosc  jest rowna to jej nie dodajemy do drzewka aby potem mozna bylo zliczyc el drzewa
                // a kazdy z nich bedzie inny
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            nodeToAdd->up = pom;
        }
    }
}
int numOfDifferentElements(BSTree* root, int counter)
{
    if (root)
    {
        counter++;
        numOfDifferentElements(root->left, counter);
        numOfDifferentElements(root->right, counter);
    }
    else
    {
        return counter;
    }
}
void judgeArray(int array[], int x)
{
    BSTree* pom = NULL;
    int lengthOfArray = *(&array +1 ) - array; // rozmiar naszej tablicy
    for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++)
    {
        AddBstNode(pom, array[i]); // tworzymy drzewo z elementow naszej tablicy
    }
    int counter = 0;
    int judge = numOfDifferentElements(pom, counter); // zliczamy liczbe el drzewa, bez zadnych zalozen, bo
    //wszystkie jego elementy sa rozne co zostalo zapewnione w funkcji AddBstNode ( kom. w linii 76 i 77)
    if(judge == x)
    {
        cout<<"Array is good"<<endl;
    }
    else if(judge < x)
    {
        cout<<"Array is wrong"<<endl;
    }
    else if(judge > x)
    {
        cout<<"Array is mediocre"<<endl;
    } // powyzej nasze zalozenia, jesli liczba roznych el jest mniejsza/wieksza/rowna od naszego zalozonego x ( liczby
    //roznych elementow) to tak oceniamy nasza tablice
}
int main() {
    int N[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; // przykladowa tablica
    int x = 12; // przykladowa wart x
    judgeArray(N, x); // wywolanie naszej funkcji z przykladowa wartoscia
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If that function goes through the `if` branch, there is no `return` statement. There is one in the `else` branch only. Add one inside the `if` as well, or one at the end of the function.

Comment: Note: `[-Wreturn-type]` in C++ is fairly severe. Both gcc and clang will generate really broken code when it happens. I recommend compiling everything with `-Werror=return-type`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for helping, It helped me and my code both works and also it was my first publication here so I'm amazed by such a fast answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that in your `numOfDifferentElements` function, if the `if` condition is satisified then there is **no return statement**. The problem is because the return type of the function is non-void and so you must return something. You can **solve** this by adding a `return` statement inside the `if` block or outside(after) the `else` block as shown below:

```
int numOfDifferentElements(BSTree* root, int counter)
{
    if (root)
    {
        counter++;
        numOfDifferentElements(root->left, counter);
        numOfDifferentElements(root->right, counter);
        //can also add a return statement here
    }
    else
    {
        return counter;
    }
    //or add return -1; or some other value indicating ERROR CODE  
}
```